# Solving an estimating problem with MLE of a function, condition of $\theta$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I was given a question to find the estimator $\theta$ by moments method of the function: $$f_{X}(x)= \begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{3x^2}{2\theta^3} & -\theta<x<\theta\\ 
 0& \text{else}
\end{Bmatrix}$$

The first moment is zero, and by the second moment I got that: $$\hat{\theta}= \sqrt{\frac{5S^2_x}{3}}$$

Now if I were to find the estimator with MLE, for the sports, I would find the function $L(\theta)$:

$$L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{3x_i^2}{2\theta^3} \times{I_{(-\theta<x_i<\theta)}}$$
Now I'll play a little with the condition of the Indicator variable I so that:
$$ L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\Bigl(\frac{3x_i^2}{2\theta^3}\Bigr) \times I_{(-\theta<\min(x_i))} \times I_{(\max(x_i)<\theta}$$
Suppose I ignore the constant $ \prod_{i=1}^{n}\Bigl(\frac{3x_i^2}{2}\Bigr)$ part, and I'm only trying to convert the condition on $x$ to a condition of $\theta$, but I'm in a little problem here:
$$-\theta<\min(x_i) \rightarrow-\min(x_i)<\theta$$
And
$$\max(x_i)<\theta $$
Eventually I can only tell what is smallr than $\theta$, but not what bounds it from above.
Virtually I'm looking for a condition such as $$f(x_i) <\theta<g(x_i)$$
where $f$ and $g$ are some functions that probably involve $\max$ or $\min$.
Can anyone direct me where can I extract a condition of an upper bound?

Comment: The likelihood is $L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n{\frac{3x_i^2}{2\theta^3}}\times{I_{(-\theta<x_i<\theta)}}$.

Comment: Where you have $S_x$ you should have $S_X,$ for reasons I would think would be obvious.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I know it is, but Im trying to write a condition of $\theta$ so that I can state what value of $\theta$ brings the function $L(\theta)$ to a max point

Comment: That is fine but wouldn't you write the correct likelihood for starters? Did you notice the missing $x_i$ in your formula? The condition you are looking for is $|x_i|<\theta$ and hence $\max |x_i|<\theta$. Or from where you stopped, $\theta>\max\{-\min x_i,\max x_i\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align} \require{cancel}
L(\theta) = {} & \prod_{i=1}^n \xcancel{\frac{3x^2}{2\theta^3}} \times{I_{(-\theta<x_i<\theta)}} \\[8pt]
L(\theta) = {} & \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{3x_i^2}{2\theta^3} \times{I_{(-\theta<x_i<\theta)}} \\[8pt]
= {} & \text{constant} \times \frac 1 {(2\theta^3)^n} \times I_{\theta > \max_i\{x_i\}} \times I_{\theta>-\min_i\{x_i\}} \\[8pt]
& \text{(where “constant'' means not depending on $\theta$)}
\end{align}

So $L(\theta)$ increases as $\theta>0$ decreases, UNTIL $\theta$ gets as small as $\max\{\pm x_1,\ldots,\pm x_n\}.$

Comment: Got your answer. Thank you